# How does one prove, or what is required for a 'strictly monotonically increasing function'F,(1)to be continuous and (2)/or surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, functional-equations, inverse-function, functional-inequalities

What is generally required to ensure that a strictly monotonically increasing function,is continuous and/or surjective?

F is an (injective) function F: $[0,1]\to [0,1]$
2. F strictly monotonically increasing 
3. F is a continuous' function  on $[0,1]$
4.. $F(1)=1$ and $F(0)=0$

To prove that F is sur-jective;and bijective  function is derived on the basis of unique Global minima and global maxima, (where F(1)=1 and F(0)=0, are said maxima and minima, for example), set at the end points of both domain and co-domains via the extreme and intermediate value theorems?

Is this how sur-jectivity is often derived, that is via the extreme and intermediate value theorems using continuity and strict monotinicity?

Ie by the **extreme value theorem,** the function it will attain its  maximum and minimum values in its range at those, and that by the Intermediate value theorem**  the Function will attain all values in the co-domain between those two points.

Thus, if the maximum and minimum function values are equal in value to end points of the co-domain and domain respectly, and occur, only at the end points of the domain,(injective)? Is that correct

ie at F(1)=max, F(0)=min, then the function will attain every value between the f those, max and minimum points.

That is for every y in the co-domain $[0,1]$,such that yjust is [0,1] it will be sur-jective, but as it is in-jective (as  F is strictly monotonic increasing) it will be bi-jective as well. Is that correct.?

ill a Midpoint Convex on f:[0,1] to [0,1] with F(0)=0 and F(1)=0; Strictly Increasing, non-negative, and Strictly Quasi convex and strictly quasi concave and concave, be continuous for is instance. It is bounded in some sense of the word? (that satifies the above constraints, but with continuity replaced by midpoint convexity, and F(0.5)=0.5

Comment: I highlighted 5, and 3, because I want to know the general conditions for surjectivity, as strict quasi convexity and midpoint convexity generally entail convexity and thus continuity,

 And is it correct that by the extreme and intermediate value theorems, 
that given the min and max points located at the min and max points of the co-domain and domain as above, and equal in value to them?. Ie

Comment: That given continuity this would  entail that F is  surjection on[0,1].

 ie, that if F, is continuous, the function F(x) will limit and attain the max and min values, 1, 0, f(1)=1, and F(0)=0, (by the extreme value theorem) but as these just are the values of the min and max co-domain, by the intermediate value theorem it will attain at least once, every values betwixt them (which just is the co-domain), and thus given in-jectivity (strictly monotonically increasing, it will be bi-jective as well) to those